# Assigning instance to Class in java

Tags: java, object

```
 public class twoinstance
{
    int a;
    public static void main()
    {
        String name =  twoinstance.class.getName();
        name c = new name();
    }
}
```

I know this code will not compile, but how can I achieve functionality like this?

Comment: `name` is a variable name, it's not a type.

Comment: Ok. *Now* would be a good time to start learning Java.

Comment: You can store the class as `Class<?>` and then call the constructor via [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `name` is a String reference, not a type. I think you wanted something like

```
Class<?> name = twoinstance.class;
try {
    Object c = name.newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String name = twoinstance.class.getName();` shall give you the fully qualified class name (including package name)

Use [Class#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) - Creates a new instance of the class represented by this Class object.

```
    Object o = Class.forName(name).newInstance();
    if(o instanceof twoinstance)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```